# Dapper - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, dapper

I've recently been playing around with dapper, but I've run into a bit of a problem regarding getting data from other tables.

My database has two tables, Users and Post. I've created two classes for these tables.

My User class

```
 public class User
 {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
 }
```

My Post class

```
  public class Post
 {
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
 }
```

This is my query to fetch all the post data from my database, and also get the Username who created the post.

```
    public IEnumerable<Post> GetPosts()
    {
        string myQuery = "SELECT p.Title, p.PublishDate, p.PostId, p.UserId, u.Username FROM Post p INNER JOIN Users u ON p.UserId = u.UserId";

        sqlConnection.Open();
        var posts = sqlConnection.Query<Post>(myQuery);

        return posts;
    }
```

Here is my view code where I want to display the information:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcDapperIntro.Models.Post>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Posts";
}

@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    <h3>@post.Title</h3>
    <p>@post.PublishDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</p>
    <p>@post.User.Username</p>
}
```

However, when I run my code, I get the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error. Is this because I shouldn't be using:

```
public User User { get; set; }
```

to access the username property, or should I create a new class with a username field. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, is there a stack trace that hints at what is failing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I get the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error

I bet the issue is on this line: `<p>@post.User.Username</p>` and that is because you did not map the User object. You should change this code:

```
var posts = sqlConnection.Query<Post>(myQuery);
```

to this:

```
var posts = sqlConnection.Query<Post, User, Post>(
                myQuery,
                (p, u) => { p.User = u; return p; }
                );
```

Comment: Thanks @VON V. I actually figured it out in the early hours of the morning, but completely forgot to update the post. Since then I've been playing around with the idea of getting data from three tables. Would I use the data from one query, and then use that result in the second query?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't quite get what you're asking. Do you want to do multiple selects and be able to map that to multiple objects?

Comment: Sorry von v, I really should have explained that better. If I had three tables, just say User, Post and Comments. Is it possible to map the data from these three tables to one object. Similar to query above, which gets data from two tables.

Comment: That's saying you want a multi map + multiple results. I was looking for something like that as well but was not able to find anything on the web. So what I do for that kind of thing is do it separately. I would love to see a member of SO provides a better alternative.